# ASP.NET Membership installation wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, installation, membership-provider

How install asp.net membership provider from C# code ? input is only connection string. Thats all.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at Scott Mitchell's walk-through of getting up and running with ASP.NET Membership (along with Roles, Profile) here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

It's a pretty lengthy, but very detailed, series of posts.  Hopefully it provides you the information you need.  Part 3 of his series will walk you through setting up the SQL side of membership, with how to run the appropriate SQL scripts, etc. to get everything ready for your code.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could shell out (Process.Start(xxx)) to [aspnet_regiis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx).exe